# How can I access properties of an item in a StackPanel in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
<ListBox x:Name="noteListBox" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FF329BD6" Margin="0,24,0,85">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="noteTitle"
                            FontSize="40"
                            Text="{Binding Titolo}"
                            Tag="{Binding FileName}"
                            Foreground="#FF45B1EE" Tap="apriNota" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="noteDateCreated"
                            Text="{Binding DateCreated}"
                            Margin="10,0,0,10" Foreground="#FF60ADD8" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I need to dynamically change the Foreground color of those two `TextBlocks` inside the `StackPanel`. The problem is that they don't seem to be accessible from my C# code, suppose because they're in that `StackPanel`.

So basically this is what I need to do:

```
noteTitle.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 155, 214));
```

But I can't even find `noteTitle` in my C# code... How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using value converter for such purposes. I assume foreground value depends on a state of object whcih ahs proeprties `FileName`, `DateCreated` you bind to, so just use this object as converetr parameter and in converter do main calculation to decide which Foreground should be returned for this particular item.

```cs
public class EntityToForegroundConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, 
                         Type targetType, 
                         object parameter, 
                         CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        var entity = value as IMyEntity;
        // TODO: determine a foreground value based on bound 
        // object proerrty values
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
                              Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, 
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Control.Resources>
    <src:EntityToForegroundConverter x:Key="foregroundConverter"/>
</Control.Resources>

<TextBlock 
   Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource foregroundConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get element you can use this code:
  var a = noteListBox.ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as StackPanel;
            (a as StackPanel).Background = Brushes.Red;

```
        foreach (UIElement  child in a.Children)
        {
            if (child is TextBlock)
                if ((child as TextBlock).Name.CompareTo("noteDateCreated") == 0)
                {
                    (child as TextBlock).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                }
        }
```

or you want change change Template ,you can create Template by code,and overWrite Template:

DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(typeof(Test));
            FrameworkElementFactory spOuterFactory =new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            FrameworkElementFactory block1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            FrameworkElementFactory block2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

```
        block1.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        Binding binding1 = new Binding();
        binding1.Path = new PropertyPath("Titolo");
        block1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding1);

        block2.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        Binding binding2 = new Binding();
        binding2.Path = new PropertyPath("noteDateCreated");
        block2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding2);         


        spOuterFactory.AppendChild(block1);
        spOuterFactory.AppendChild(block2);

        template.VisualTree = spOuterFactory;
        noteListBox.ItemTemplate = template;
```